# Create rectangle with curved side

Tags: android, shapes

I am attempting to create a shape to "border" a button (linked below with the asterisk inside). I have a rounded button to the right that I have I already created, but have become stuck trying to create the other shape.

I have had many attempts at this, but none seem to work and it's incredibly frustrating.

Just to note, that the shape I want is currently a TextView and houses a number "1:" through to "4:"

Any help at all will be appreciated.

Image of what I am attempting to achieve:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/r5krvv84d/]

Comment: Use PNG image instead..

Comment: Does that "expand" so to speak? Like, if the size of the button appears differently (size wise) on another device, will the left-hand shape also still fit nicely?

Comment: ya. Obviously. You need to place different size of such images in "hdpi","xhdpi","xxhdpi" etc directories. This will not let you blur that image. It is also good like to use **9patch** image. So that will stretch from middle not from sides.